# Generics and Inheritance?

Tags: java, generics

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    List<Child> list1 = new ArrayList<Child>();
    method2(list1);
}

public static void method2(List<Parent> list1) {
}
```

I get below compilation error

> The method method2(List) is undefined ...

Above issue can be solved with modifying `List<Parent> list1` to `List<? extends Parent> list1`.

But if i try to add child object like below

```
public static void method2(List<? extends Parent> list1) {
    Child child1 = new Child();
    list1.add(child1);
}
```

It gives compilation error again

> The method add(capture#1-of ? extends Parent) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Child)

So my question is if `List<Child>` can be passed as parameter to `List<? extends Parent> list1` why we can't add child object under `List<? extends Parent>`?

Comment: pls post the def for Child and Parent class

Comment: See the PECS rules. You could have a class `Child2 extends Parent`. If it was allowed then you could add a `Child` instance to a `List<Child2>`.

Comment: As an unrelated note, I start twitching every time I see `class Child extends Parent {}`. Children should not be parents!!! [LSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). `Parent parent = new Child();` is a nonsensical analogy for inheritance.

Comment: That's because you are thinking of Child and Parent in terms of biology, not class relationships. The fact that he never mentioned that Child extended Parent and everyone understood the question is telling.

Comment: @DanielL. In fact, I often see parent/child used *specifically* as a biological analogy (see e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.htmlcenter.com/blog/object-oriented-programming-parents-and-children/) which I found on the first page of Google). Also, we would have understood the question if the OP used `class Gidget extends Gadget {}`. Could have been anything. Anyway, I wasn't criticizing the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common misunderstanding. The fact the Child extends Parent does not make `List<Child>` extend `List<Parent>`. Sounds very unintuitive in cases like this one, but there it is. From the java tutorial:

> Given two concrete types A and B (for example, Number and Integer),
>   MyClass< A> has no relationship to MyClass< B>, regardless of whether or
>   not A and B are related. The common parent of MyClass and
>   MyClass is Object.

Read [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/inheritance.html) for details.

As for adding to the list, the short answer is: Imagine you have a another `class Child2 extends Parent`, now, the list you are receiving as a parameter at `method2(List<? extends Parent> list1)` could be either a `List<Child1>` or a `List<Child2>`. Thus, given that the second case is possible, adding a Child1 object is not type safe.

Now, the fact that you can't add does not mean that you can't do other useful stuff, like getting the size, etc.

Comment: Second case is also showing compile time error `...is not applicable for the arguments (Child2)`

Comment: Of course, it is perfectly symmetric. I was giving an example of why it would fail for both given that you can't know what actual type of object is in your list, not saying that it would work for Child2

Comment: Really its very confusing. Looks like i have to mug up this one which i don't like.

Comment: Another way to explain this would be this: You method receives a parameter "list of something that extends Parent", not knowing what 'something' is. Thus, you are limited to the operations that do not require to know it: attributes of the list, picking an element and using it as a normal Parent pointer, etc. On the other hand, you can't add a new 'something' without knowing what it should be.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is if `List<Child>` can be passed as parameter to `List<? extends Parent>` `list1` why we can't add child object under `List<? extends Parent>`?

Suppose we could. Now suppose we had:

```
class Parent {}
class Mother extends Parent {}
class Father extends Parent {}

static void m(List<? extends Parent> parents) {
    parents.add(new Father());
}

List<Mother> mothers = new ArrayList<>();
m(mothers);
// throws 'ClassCastException: cannot cast Father to Mother'
Mother actuallyAFather = mothers.get(0);
```

A `List<? extends Parent>` is a List which stores at most `Parent`, or perhaps some subtype of `Parent`, which we don't have knowledge of anymore. We can't add anything to it except null.

So perhaps what you want is:

```
public static void method2(List<? super Child> list1) {
//                                ^^^^^^^^^^^
    Child child1 = new Child();
    list1.add(child1);
}
```

A `List<? super Child>` is a List which we can add a `Child` to. Maybe it's a `List<Parent>` or maybe it's a `List<Child>`, but we don't care. We only care that it's a List we can add a `Child` to.

Also see:

- [Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>? Why aren't Java's generics implicitly polymorphic?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)
- [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs)

Answer (score 0):

**Here is my own answer after reading more stuff**

We can not assign `List<Dog> to List<Animal>` because `List<Animal>` means we can add any animal like cat, dog to it 
whereas  `List<Dog>` means we can add only dog/sub types to it but not cat. So assigner will think he will get only dog/sub types
but he can get cat object also(so run time error)

Here is the example

```
psvm{
List<Dog> list1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
list1.add(new Dog()); 
method1(list1);// compilation error
}

public static void method1(List<Animal> list1) {
list1.add(cat); // Good
list1.add(dog); // Good
}
```

Another common misconception is about upper bounded Generics which is exactly opposite of

When we say `List<? extends Animal> list1` we can not add any value except null but yes we can assign any Animal/Sub types
If we allow adding it means it can contains any animal like cat, dog but while retrieval(i.e down-casting) we don't what actually
it is type of.

```
psvm{
List<Dog> list1 = new ArrayList<Dog>();
list1.add(new Dog()); 
method1(list1);// good
}

public static void method1(List<? extends Animal> list1) {
list1.add(cat); // compilation error
list1.add(dog); // compilation error
}
```